# Floating Thumbnails

Tags: html, css

i'm attempting to create a responsive image gallery, i've got the images responsive but i'm having a problem with whitespace.

I've given the items margin:0 and padding:0 but I am getting unwanted white sapce and i'm not sure how to handle it.

HTML:

```
<ul class="thumbnail-view">
  <li class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/600/600" />
    <span class="overlay">
        testing
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/600/600" />
    <span class="overlay">
        testing
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/600/600" />
    <span class="overlay">
        testing
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/600/600" />
    <span class="overlay">
        testing
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
  body,html{
  margin:0;
}


.thumbnail-view{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.thumbnail{
width: 25%;
position: relative;
display: block;
float:left;
cursor: pointer;

img{ 
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}

.overlay{
    top: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
    right: 15px;   
    left: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: rgba(33, 177, 167, 0.7);
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s;
    transition: opacity 0.6s;
    color:#fff;
}

&:hover .overlay{
    opacity:1;    
}

}
```

here's the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/kmcbride/2b4yW/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images are inline block elements so they have white space. To remove it, you can add `display:block;` to the images.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/2b4yW/8/)**